# Radiobutton change event with jQuery doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Here's a JSFiddle example so you see what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/stapiagutierrez/yVzR5/

The event is supposed to fire on the selection of the payment option change, but it's only firing when I specifically click on the radio button.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to trigger the event yourself

```
    $('.paymentoption').click(function () {
        $(this).find('input[name="paymenttype"]').prop('checked', true).change();

        // or trigger('change');
    });
```

Comment: any idea why you have to trigger it yourself?